# Show only files owned by the user

Tags: linux, file-permissions, inode

I have a folder containing lots of backup images. I want users to only see their own files. I've tried setting the permissions to `000` but they still can see the file using `ls` (the backups belong to the user, set by `chown`).

I tried symlinking (creating the symlink in their `/home/` directory and denied access to the backup folder), but it doesn't work. FTP sees the file as a folder and not as a file.
Hardlinking does work, but when a new backup is written, the `inode` is changed and therefore breaking the hardlink.

Is there any other way I'm not thinking about?

Comment: Listing a directory is permitted through *its* read permission. Maybe distribute the files across subdirectories, owned by the respective users, with `700` permission?

Comment: @DanielBeck We've got a complete backup system in place, it would be too much work to change everything hence I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Remove read permission from the folder containing the backups, but keep the `x` perm. Then write a cron script that creates a secondary structure: One folder per user, containing symlinks to all their own files. Restrict read access to these folders to the respective users. This way, you can keep your output in place and take users' ability to see others'  backups while keeping their own backups accessible. (you could also hardlink these, but that'd make cleanup more difficult -- now you'd just delete the actual backup file, and the next cron job script run would clear away obsolete symlinks).